# How to make generic HTTPClient request call?

Tags: angular, typescript2.0, angular5

In Angular 5 , i can make `http`  calls with generic like,

```
http.get<Employee>(....) ...
```

How to make this generic concept work with `request` method of `HttpClient` ? I have tried the following.

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {} 

    private fire<T>(options: CustomRequestOptions) {
       return this.http.request<T>(options.request);
    }
}
```

I do not have complete knowledge on typescript and it doesn't seems to be the correct way of implementation as well.

Comment: your code should work perfectly fine. what is the issue you are facing

Comment: 1. if i make a call `this.dataService.fire<Employee>(options)`, and debug it, i get `T is undefined` reference error in the chrome developer tool. 
2. i am wondering is it proper to have a generic method inside a non generic class

Answer (score 1):

`any` is your way to go :

```js
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {} 

    private fire<any>(options: CustomRequestOptions) {
       return this.http.request<any>(options.request);
    }
}
```